Strange problem trying to transfer an SPL token on solana (rust & ts) I'm getting "Incorrect Program ID. I need a keen eye to sort out the problem
I used the following Rust code to try to transfer spl tokens between wallets using ATAs of the respective wallets for the given token.
The from.key is the authority for the transfer.
    let transfer_instruction = spl_token::instruction::transfer_checked(
        &spl_token_2022::ID,
        from_acct.key, // from ATA
        mint.key,
        to_acct.key,   // to ATA
        from.key,      //Authority
        &[from.key],
        amount,
        5).unwrap();    
    msg!("Transfer Inst Formed{:?}!"); // Doesn't make it to here
                                       // says, "IncorrectProgramId" ???
    // The mint and ATAs use token prog 22 as the mint has a metadata extension

    let required_accounts_for_transfer = [
        from_acct.clone(),
        mint.clone(),
        to_acct.clone(),
        from.clone(),
    ];

    invoke_signed(
        &transfer_instruction,
        &required_accounts_for_transfer,
        &[],
    ).unwrap();

The ATAs were created (in ts) with the following :
tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        keypair,
        mintPK,
        keypair.publicKey, // This for "From"
//        escwallet.publicKey, //Then this for "To"
        false,
        null,
        {},
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      );

keypair.publicKey was used for the From Account and
escwallet.publicKey was used for the desination Account
It doesn't make it past the creation of the instruction.
I get the following error at the end of the Tx creation:
"Program log: Transfer 100000 from: 4Qeo9ttdf4vCZTC4d2pGq4eqFfkQpxj95t4WGYc2buXV to: 86YUbdsc7z2Y5NdLXeFLwVYfbzVdLjUb1en9XxmJbfb2!",

"Program log: for mint: GSLS3jfAf6F8Bimab8dvAgc3Xz5rewa2KBKumjhoNn11",
"Program log: panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IncorrectProgramId', 574155a2-81d8-4c76-b5d1-fff88cd66c8d/src/lib.rs:221:12",

TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb is being used!
What I don't understand, I did the same transaction with Phantom (successfully).
The Phantom transaction calculates compute unit budgets, which I don't, but I don't think this causes my error!
Otherwise all the parameters are the same.
